# How to protect against Replay Attacks

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to figure out a way to implement decent crypto on a micro-controller project. I have an ARMv4 based MCU that will control my garage door and receive commands over a WiFi module.

The MCU will run a TCP/IP server, that will listen for commands from Android clients that can connect from anywhere on the Internet, which is why I need to implement crypto.

I understand how to use AES with shared secret key to properly encrypt traffic, but I am finding it difficult to deal with Replay Attacks. All solutions I see so far have serious drawbacks.

There are two fundamental problems which prevent me from using well
established methods like session tokens, timestamps or nonces:

1. The MCU has no reliable source of entropy, so I can't generate
   quality random numbers.
2. The attacker can reset the MCU by cutting power to the garage,
   thus erasing any stored state at will, and resetting time counter to
   zero (or just wait 49 days until it loops).

With these restrictions in mind, I can see only one approach that seems
ok to me (i.e. I don't see how to break it yet). Unfortunately, this
requires non-volatile storage, which means writing to external flash,
which introduces some serious complexity due to a variety of technical details.

I would love to get some feedback on the following solution. Even better, is there a solution I am missing that does not require non-volatile storage?

Please note that the primary purpose of this project is education. I realize that I could simplify this problem by setting up a secure relay inside my firewall, and let that handle Internet traffic, instead of exposing the MCU directly. But what would be the fun in that? ;)

**= Proposed Solution =**

A pair of shared AES keys will be used. One key to turn a Nonce into an IV for the CBC stage, and another for encrypting the messages themselves:

- Shared message `Key`
- Shared `IV_Key`

Here's a picture of what I am doing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNsUrOVQKpE#t=10m11s

1) Android takes current time in milliseconds (`Ti`) (64-bit long) and
    uses it as a nonce input into the CBC stage to encrypt the command:

```
a) IV(i) = AES_ECB(IV_Key, Ti)
b) Ci = AES_CBC(Key, IV(i), COMMAND)
```

2) Android utilizes `/dev/random` to generate the `IV_Response` that the
MCU will use to answer current request.

3) Android sends `[<Ti, IV_Response, Ci>, <== HMAC(K)]`

4) MCU receives and verifies integrity using HMAC, so attacker can't
modify plain text `Ti`.

5) MCU checks that `Ti > T(i-1)` stored in flash. This ensures that
recorded messages can't be replayed.

6) MCU calculates `IV(i) = AES_ECB(IV_Key, Ti)` and decrypts `Ci`.

7) MCU responds using `AES_CBC(Key, IV_Response, RESPONSE)`

8) MCU stores `Ti` in external flash memory.

Does this work? Is there a simpler approach?

**EDIT:** It was already shown in comments that this approach is vulnerable to a Delayed Playback Attack. If the attacker records and blocks messages from reaching the MCU, then the messages can be played back at any later time and still be considered valid, so this algorithm is no good.

As suggested by @owlstead, a challenge/response system is likely required. Unless I can find a way around that, I think I need to do the following:

- Port or implement a decent PRGA. (**Any recommendations?**)
- Pre-compute a lot of random seed values for the PRGA. A new seed will be used for every MCU restart. Assuming 128-bit seeds, 16K of storage buys be a 1000 unique seeds, so the values won't loop until the MCU successfully uses at least one PRGA output value and restarts a 1000 times. That doesn't seem too bad.
- Use the output of PRGA to generate the challenges.

Does that sound about right?

Comment: Something tells me that for a challenge response protocol you should first send a challenge from the door, and then - within a certain time frame - accept a challenge. Now an attacker can just catch the encrypted commands before they ever reach the door and open the door at any time (by forwarding the captured messages).

Comment: Ah, within a certain time frame, "accept the (authenticated) challenge **response**".

Comment: @owlstead You are right - my algorithm appears to be vulnerable to the attack you describe. I was thinking about using a challenge/response approach for each request, but that would require the MCU to be able to select unique Nonces. This in turn requires a PRGA, and since there is no randomness available, it will also require a pre-computed table of seeds, so we can use a new one on every restart. I was hoping to avoid having to implement or port a PRGA, but perhaps I'll have to after all. Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: You can just use a nonce as challenge instead - a challenge does not have to be random, although it would require an EEPROM write to update the counter (always update the counter *in advance*). Maybe use the [Kerberos method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication#Cryptographic_techniques) of challenge response.

Answer (score 1):

Having an `IV_KEY` is unnecessary. IVs (and similar constructs, such as salts) do not need to be encrypted, and if you look at image you linked to in the youtube video you'll see their description of the payload includes the IV in plaintext. They are used so that the same plaintext does not encode to the same ciphertext under the same key every time, which presents information to an attacker. The protection against the IV being altered is the HMAC on the message, not the encryption. As such, you can remove that requirement. **EDIT:** This paragraph is incorrect, see discussion below. As noted though, your approach described above will work fine.

Your system does have a flaw though, namely the `IV_Response`. I assume, from that you include it in your system, that it serves some purpose. However, because it is not in any way encoded, it allows an attacker to respond affirmatively to a device's request without the MCU receiving it. Let's say that your device's were instructing an MCU that was running a small robot to throw a ball. Your commands might look like.

```
1) Move to loc (x,y).
2) Lower anchor to secure bot table.
3) Throw ball
```

Our attacker can allow messages 1 and 3 to pass as expected, and block 2 from getting to the MCU while still responding affirmatively, causing our bot to be damaged when it tosses the ball without being anchored. This does have an imperfect solution. Append the response (which should fit into a single block) to the command so that it is encrypted as well, and have the MCU respond with `AES_ECB(Key, Response)`, which the device will verify. As such, the attacker will not be able to forge (feasibly) a valid response. Note that as you consider `/dev/random` untrustworthy this could provide an attacker with plaintext-ciphertext pairs, which can be used for linear cryptanalysis of the key provided an attacker has a large set of pairs to work with. As such, you'll need to change the key with some regularity.

Other than that, your approach looks good. Just remember it is crucial that you use the stored `Ti` to protect against the replay attack, and not the MCU's clock. Otherwise you run into synchronization problems.

Comment: In CBC the IV needs to be indistinguishable from random to the attacker as well, even if it is public. That's one of the tricky things about CBC. Encryption of a nonce with a different key is certainly a good method of achieving this.

Comment: @owlstead Interesting. Block ciphers are not my forte so I've only seen some basic discussion of them, and I certainly haven't seen the weakness you mention. I can even quote directly from Schneier (granted, his _Applied Cryptography_, which is somewhat out of date) that "a timestamp often makes a good IV". What's the reasoning behind the necessity for the IV to be indistinguishable from random?

Comment: @owlstead Nevermind, found a [nice SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008139/why-is-using-a-non-random-iv-with-cbc-mode-a-vulnerability). Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @SamuelJudson I am not sure how the attacker could respond affirmatively to command #2. IV_Response is used in conjunction with Key to encrypt the response from our hypothetical robot. Yes, the attacker has IV_Response, but w/o Key, how would the attacker make a valid response that could fool the client?

Comment: @SamuelJudson Oh I see - I think I was unclear in my Step 7. What I meant to say there is that MCU responds using AES_CBC(Key, IV_Response, RESPONSE).